# Given a 'tree' like data structure, print out all the paths from leaf to root

Tags: computer-science

Could somebody guide me in the right direction with this please, I don't understand how to return the results from leaf to root

```
tree = {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "child1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "grand_child1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "grand_child2",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "child2",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:
The solution should be an algorithm, in that if tree depth is increased it should still work

Comment: The algorithm you are looking for is 'recursive descent' - you want to look at the `children` element of each value in the map, then recursively evaluate the  children of that object until you find an object with an empty list of children.  That is your leaf node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion, e.g:

```
def traverse(node, *names, &block)
  names.unshift(node[:name])

  yield *names and return if node[:children].empty?

  node[:children].each { |child| traverse(child, *names, &block) }
end
```

The method operates on a single node. On each invocation, it adds the node's name to a list of gathered `names` (initially empty). It then calls itself again for each child, passing `names`. If a node doesn't have any children, it yields `names` to the given block. (which is passed along too)

Usage:

```
traverse(tree) do |*names|
  p name: names
end
```

Output:

```
{:name=>["grand_child1", "child1", "root"]}
{:name=>["grand_child2", "child1", "root"]}
{:name=>["child2", "root"]}
```

Comment: Lovely! Readers: note that `yield *names` could be expressed `block.call *names`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def explore_tree(tree, names=[])
  names = [tree[:name]] + names
  if tree[:children].empty?
    p names
  else
    tree[:children].each { |child| explore_tree(child, names) }
  end
end
```

```
explore_tree(tree)
```

displays

```
["grand_child1", "child1", "root"]
["grand_child2", "child1", "root"]
["child2", "root"]
```

Comment: I normally provide some explanation but in this case it does not seem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
def get_paths(hash)
  # Stop method and return name if name is address
  return hash[:name] if hash[:children].empty?
  paths = [] # Declaring path variable
  # Inspecting children
  hash[:children].each do |child|
    child_paths = get_paths(child)
    if child_paths.is_a? String
      paths << [child_paths, hash[:name]]
    else
      child_paths.each { |path| path << hash[:name] }
      paths += child_paths
    end
  end
  paths # Return paths
end

p *get_paths(tree).map { |path| path.to_s[1..-2] }
# => "grand_child1", "child1,", "root"
# => "grand_child2", "child1,", "root"
# => "child2", "root"
```

Comment: Your solution would only work if you know the depth of the tree, let's say the depth is unknown

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Haven't you seen the method works with different depths?

Comment: sorry what I meant was that your solution relies on a hardcoded address,

Comment: Thanks Chiara appreciate it